# self|personal development, advance javascript

Tags: javascript

It might not sound like a real question to some people, sorry about that.
I have been working with javascript(pure javascript and jquery) along with php,html and css) for now about 4 years but I cannot understand anything if I look at javascript codes(unminified) on pages such as those from google, or facebook or jquery etc. I want to understand those codes in order to improve my javascript skills.

How can I make myself understand such codes?
Thanks a lot for your efforts on helping me improve.

Comment: Practise practise practise. Google "codewars". Nice site for developing your programming skills.

Comment: The only way you're going to understand anything is by trying to understand yourself, if you have people explain you what everything does it's not going to help. First look at the code, put aside the stuff you understand, and focus on what you don't understand yet, look at the docs, try to combine the small things you understand and try from there to figure out what's being done. Maybe code from these sites is not the best way to learn as they're made to be efficient, not readable, even if you un-obfuscate them.

Comment: @DanielShillcock and luda thanks. the problem is much of the code seems different from what one can learn from a javascript book, in the books it says eval is not good practise, but you find them there often

Comment: We write code (code in general) to solve some problem. In a sense, the code has to have purposes.
We cannot jump into the source code of a strange system and hope to understand everything. 
Even the authors cannot understand the whole system. Most of the time one can only understand the part of code he/she writes.

Comment: @JonDoe the thing is "good" or "bad" practice is not something everyone is willing to apply,  and if it makes things faster to develop and is just "good enough" it's much more likely to be used. Also if you take `goto` in most languages is considered bad practice as it makes the code harder to read in most cases. People will usually agree that you should stay away from it, but there are cases (especially in kernels where speed is important) where it makes things more efficient, and in that case it is not really "bad practice" anymore. Depends on how you use such functions.

Comment: thanks for your comments, could you please share your experience, how did you make it to this point in terms of your javascript skills.

Comment: @JonDoe I've never written any javascript actually, I'm a C programmer, what I said here applies to all languages and all paradigms. Do not forget that being a developer is not about being a <insert-language>-developer (as shown in this webcomic http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2016/09/09/the-mistakes-of-youth/ ). There's no magic way to become good at <insert-language>, you have to practice, read other people's code, try to understand things, read the docs... But the most important part is "try to solve things by yourself". You're the only person that will teach you something, nobody can do that

Comment: When I say nobody can teach you something I mean that everybody can explain you anything, but if you do not understand it yourself then you have not learned anything, therefore understanding something, which only you can do, is the only way to learn something. In simpler words : listen, read, try, understand and learn.

Comment: @LudaOtaku and everyonr else, thanks a lot